# Using ShellExecuteEx in c# with Unicode Filename

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I need to use ShellExecuteExin c#
my filename has unicode character when I pass filename to ShellExecuteEx it throws exception
cant find file

When function finisheed unicode character in filename change to '?'

```
    [Serializable]
    public struct ShellExecuteInfo
    {
        public int Size;
        public uint Mask;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public string Verb;
        public string File;
        public string Parameters;
        public string Directory;
        public uint Show;
        public IntPtr InstApp;
        public IntPtr IDList;
        public string Class;
        public IntPtr hkeyClass;
        public uint HotKey;
        public IntPtr Icon;
        public IntPtr Monitor;
    }

    // Code For OpenWithDialog Box
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    extern public static bool
           ShellExecuteEx(ref ShellExecuteInfo lpExecInfo);

    public const uint SW_NORMAL = 1;

    public static void OpenAs(string file)
    {
        ShellExecuteInfo sei = new ShellExecuteInfo();
        sei.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(sei);
        sei.Verb = "openas";
        sei.File = file;
        sei.Show = SW_NORMAL;
        if (!ShellExecuteEx(ref sei))
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
    }
```

Comment: This is unnecessary, use the .NET ProcessStartInfo.Verb property.

Answer (score 2):

The default character set is ANSI. So you need to specify the character set to be Unicode:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct ShellExecuteInfo
{
    ....
}

....

[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool ShellExecuteEx(ref ShellExecuteInfo lpExecInfo);
```

Although personally, since this long struct is only ever passed by reference, and since you invariably use `new` to ensure initialization, I'd declare it as a class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class ShellExecuteInfo
{
    ....
}

....

[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool ShellExecuteEx(ShellExecuteInfo lpExecInfo);
```

Note that we removed the `ref` because a class is a reference type. As opposed to a struct which is a value type.

I would also comment that you got the field translation incorrect, at the icon/monitor union. A corrected translation would be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class ShellExecuteInfo
{
    public int Size;
    public uint Mask;
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public string Verb;
    public string File;
    public string Parameters;
    public string Directory;
    public int Show;
    public IntPtr InstApp;
    public IntPtr IDList;
    public string Class;
    public IntPtr hkeyClass;
    public uint HotKey;
    public IntPtr IconOrMonitor;
    public IntPtr Process;
}
```

Finally, for convenience, it is worth adding a constructor to the class to initialize the size field:

```
public ShellExecuteInfo()
{
    Size = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
}
```

---

Of course, you can just use `Process.Start` for the code in the question:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.Verb = "openas";
psi.FileName = file;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: when i used ShellExecuteInfo --> windows can not find C (The path is "C:/MyDownloads") and when used ProcessStartInfo  --> "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation"

Comment: You aren't using the code in my answer. You need both CharSet. You are missing it on the function. Process.Start calls ShellExecuteEx. Switching from Process.Start to ShellExecuteEx changes nothing.

Comment: I used charset but didn't work. i used your answer but did'nt work

Comment: Works here. Can't imagine what you are doing wrong. Use the code in the answer passing "open" as the verb and "notepad" as the filename. Bear in mind that when using "openas" on a directory, receiving an error that "no association is associated with....." means that the code is working as expected.

Comment: I need open with files. when i used the code the program did not correctly. and run time error "No application is associated"

Answer (score 0):

Opening a URL

Solution 1 - PInvoke without the nasty structure

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern uint ShellExecute(IntPtr hwnd, string strOperation, string strFile, string strParameters, string strDirectory, Int32 nShowCmd);

string link = "http://www.yahoo.com";
string def = string.Empty;
IntPtr hWnd = (IntPtr)0;
uint ret = ShellExecute(hWnd, def, link, def, def, 0);
```

---

Solution 2:  Use C# native

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c start " + link) { CreateNoWindow = true });
```

---

Solution 3: More C#

```
ProcessStartInfo URL = new ProcessStartInfo();
URL.FileName = link;
URL.CreateNoWindow = true;
URL.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(URL);
```